# How to use the uploaded filename in another python script in Django

Tags: python, django, file-upload, parameter-passing

In my Django "sources" project I have the "bulletins" app.
I have a view "model_form_upload" inside of which I get the uploaded file name ("csvFilename") when I upload it.

views.py

```
from bulletins.forms import ErnageForm
from bulletins.models import ErnageModel
from bulletins.pretreatment import pretreatment

def model_form_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ErnageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            for filename, file in request.FILES.items():
                csvFilename = file.name
            resultPretreatment = pretreatment()
            print(resultPretreatment)
            return redirect('proceed_FT')
        else:
            return redirect('upload_fail')
    else:
        form = ErnageForm()
    return render(request, 'bulletins/upload_csv.html', {'form': form})
```

Beside that, I have a python script "pretreatment.py" that effectuates a bunch of pandas-dataframe transformations on my csv file.

pretreatment.py

```
def pretreatment(csvFileToTreat="..."
#... all the transformations with pandas dataframes...
df.to_csv(txtExportFilePath, index=False, header=None, sep='\t')
```

models.py

```
class ErnageModel(models.Model):
    csv = models.FileField(upload_to="METEO ERNAGE/{0}/{1}".format(yearToTreat,monthToTreat))
```

My csvFilename will always be a string of this type : "Ernageyyyymm.csv".

My question here is : How can I collect my csvFilename variable out of the views.model_form_upload function to use its date information it in the pretreatment python script variables "csvFileToTreat" and "txtExportFilePath".

Those two ones are of the type "path/Ernage{0}{1}.format(yearToTreat,monthToTreat).

As I have to use it each month I would like to have my files uploaded in `media/METEO ERNAGE/{0}/{1}".format(yearNumber,monthNumber)` as you can see in the FileField upload_to and then everything happening in this directory. So the pretreatment charges the uploaded file and then export  in it also.

I hope all this is as clear as possible, thank you for your help.

Comment: `resultPretreatment = pretreatment()` why don't you pass it as a parameter here?

Comment: @IvanStarostin I updated my question (added models.py). First I have to get the dates in the filename to upload the file in the right directory and then pretreatment.py will get this uploaded file there (media/METEO ERNAGE/yyyy/mm) and work on it to export a file in this very much directory.

Answer (score 0):

store csvFilename  name in a session like this:

```
request.session['file']=csvFilename
```

and you can use this session where ever you want like this.

```
 csvFilename =request.session['file']
```

Comment: Thanks for this tip. I now have a question with this: as my "pretreatment.py" is a python script I put beside of the views.py, it doesn't know the requests module even if I import it. How can I use it ?

Comment: you can do one thing: make a global var in views.py file let say a=' ' and assign the file name to this var then in your pretreatment.py import it as "from views import a",

Comment: After import you can use it in your  "pretreatment.py" file you can check it by printing